# How to receive Local Broadcast receiver in Adapter (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

My app shows comments and I want to have re-comments.

Comments, of course, have commentAdapter to get multiple comments data and show them.

And from `commentActivity`, if i write re-comment for one of comment, this should put that comment as re-comment.

In order to have `re-comments`, comment adapter links another recommentAdapter.

I need to send signal that user write re-comment from `Activity` to commentAdapter and add that data class to re-comment item list and run reCommentAdapter again.

For this signal I tried to use local broadcast receiver.

So from Activity, I filter intent for local broadcast receiver with extras.

```
val sendCommentAdapter = Intent(this, CommentAdapter::class.java)
                        sendCommentAdapter.setAction("RE_COMMENT_EDIT_INTENT")
                        sendCommentAdapter.putExtra("reEditCommentId", reEditCommentId)
                        sendCommentAdapter.putExtra("reEditCommentCommentId", reEditCommentCommentId)
                        sendCommentAdapter.putExtra("reEditNewDescription", newDescription)
                        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(sendCommentAdapter)
```

and I register local broadcast receiver in `onBindViewHolder()` in commentAdapter.

```
  val reEditFilter = IntentFilter()
        reEditFilter.addAction("RE_EDIT_COMMENT_ACTION")
        context.registerReceiver(reEditCommentActionReceiver, reEditFilter)
```

`reEditCommentActionReceiver` function that will run when gets broadcaset receiver, looks like below.

```
  private val reEditCommentActionReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val reEditCommentId = intent?.getStringExtra("reEditCommentId").toString()
            val reEditCommentCommentId = intent?.getStringExtra("reEditCommentCommentId").toString()
            val reEditNewDescription = intent?.getStringExtra("reEditNewDescription").toString()

            Log.d("답글: reCommentItems", "$reCommentItems")
            Log.d("답글: reEditCommentId", "$reEditCommentId")
            Log.d("답글: reEditCommentCommentId", "$reEditCommentCommentId")

            reCommentItems.forEachIndexed { index, reComment ->
                if(reComment.reCommentId == reEditCommentCommentId) {
                    reComment.commentDescription = reEditNewDescription
                    reAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I print log of getting extras from Activity, nothing comes.

So I guess this adapter can't get broadcast receiver correctly.

What is the problem? and if Adapter is not good for having local broadcast receiver, in order to implement this functions, how can I make it?

Please help me.